# How do I uninstall a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, uninstallation

I've just worked through the Rail example supplied by Apple:
http://developer.apple.com/Tools/developonrailsleopard.html

Now that I'm done, I'd like to clean this up and remove the web service, database etc. Obviously I still want the RoR stack in place.

How? Can I do this using rake?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just delete it; the whole folder that was created by the rails command you started with, in this case the expenses folder. It's all self-contained.

The rails command creates a copy of the framework, so it'll still be installed.

Comment: How is the database deleted along with it?

Comment: Sqlite stores database in your app directory, so everything will be deleted. 
If you are using other database, just delete it manually..

Answer (score 13):

You need to drop your related database and then delete the app directory

```
# from app directory
rake db:drop
cd .. && rm -rf <app_directory_name>
```

Rails generator command creates a copy of the framework. The app directory id self contained. Deleting it is enough. If you are using `sqlite` as your database then you can skip first command.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of safety, at first, it's essential to drop the tables in the database and finally deleting the app's directory.

```
rake db:drop
cd /root/of/app_directory/
rm -rf app_directory
```

Note: In some [document](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) (I am not sure about the consequences), I saw another command for dropping the database which is `rails db:drop`.